# Unable to reinstall the codedeploy-agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have removed the code deploy agent from one of the ec2 instance in region: us-west-2 using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -r codedeploy-agent
```

as mentioned in the doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html#how-to-verify-agent-version-ubuntu

To reinstall I copied the install from the s3 bucket adn when I do

```
sudo ./install auto
```

I am getting this message:

```
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:03.902026 #5227]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:03.902274 #5227]  INFO -- : The current Ruby version is not 2.0.x! Restarting the installer with /usr/bin/ruby2.0
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.043343 #5227]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.043548 #5227]  INFO -- : Starting update check.
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.043649 #5227]  INFO -- : Attempting to automatically detect supported package manager type for system...
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.048600 #5227]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_REGION environment variable for region information...
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.048712 #5227]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for region information...
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.103736 #5227]  INFO -- : Running version 1.0-1.950
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.103871 #5227]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-west-2 and key latest/VERSION...
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.169833 #5227]  INFO -- : Running version matches target version, skipping install
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.170000 #5227]  INFO -- : Update check complete.
I, [2016-05-13T14:20:04.170094 #5227]  INFO -- : Stopping updater.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg -r codedeploy-agent
```

this does't remove the codedeploy-agent completely

I ran

```
sudo apt-get purge codedeploy-agent
```

and then

```
sudo ./install auto
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

sudo dpkg --purge  would do the job.